# Yii файл index.php

Tags: yii2, yii

Начал изучать Yii 2 заказчик сказал его использовать.
после установки индексный файл доступен только с папки web/index.php
а как сделать что бы проект запускался с корневой папки, я могу поставить переадресацию, но это наверное не правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, сделали поддомен и там поставили уже документ рут как надо.

Answer (score 0):

> Начал **изучать** Yii 2 **заказчик** сказал его использовать

Круто :)

> а как сделать что бы проект запускался с корневой папки

В настройках Apache (файле *.conf) нужно изменить `DocumentRoot`, чтобы он "смотрел" в эту папку `web`. (После чего Apache необходимо перезагрузить.)

Comment: Без Апача никак, может htaccess заюзать как то?

Comment: Ну есть что-то: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512881/how-to-set-document-root-to-be-a-subdirectory-using-htaccess-and-not-vhost А что такое? Хостинг? Если на хостинге нельзя сменить DocumentRoot, даже через админов - то нужно менять хостинг. Для меня они вообще стали самым крайним эрзацем, когда есть VPS как бюджетный и слабый вариант, и DS как мощный и подороже.

Comment: У меня на сервере много других проектов я не могу, поменять документ рут, может есть какие то настройки прям в Yii?

Comment: Бред. У каждого проекта должен быть свой DocumentRoot.

Comment: Админ говорит, что только через поддомены
проект лежит в тестовой папке где все проекты разрабатываемые